# What is the proof of law of equipartition of energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, degrees-of-freedom

In thermodynamics, [law of equipartition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem) of energy states that if we have any gas sample then the total kinetic energy will be distributed among the different degrees of freedom of the gas sample. Each degree of freedom does a contribution of $\frac{1}{2}k_{b}T$ in the kinetic energy of the gas and $\frac{R}{2}$ to $C_{v}$ of the gas. Please give me a rigorous proof as to why the above is true. From where did the numbers  $\frac{1}{2}k_{b}T$ and $\frac{R}{2}$ come? ($k_{b}$ is Boltzmann constant and $R$ is universal gas constant).

Comment: Does this help? http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Kinetic/eqpar.html#c1

Comment: I think it is not really https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorema **law** but a theorem, i.e to be proven with the used of laws and mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the Example $19.1$ in ['Concepts in Thermal Physics' by Blundell and Blundell](https://bayanbox.ir/view/334073060328122555/thermalphysics-2ed-Blundell.pdf).

---

Let the energy $E$ of a particular system be given by
$$E=\alpha x^2$$
The partition function
$$Z=\int e^{-\beta \alpha x^2}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha \beta}}$$
$$\langle E\rangle =-\frac{d\ln Z}{d\beta}= \frac{1}{2\beta}$$

For $$E=\sum_i \alpha_ix_i^2$$
$$Z=\prod_i \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha_i\beta}}$$
$$\langle E\rangle =\sum_i \frac{1}{2\beta}=n\frac{1}{2\beta}$$